# Simplifying the if else statement

Tags: c++

I am trying to simplify the below `if` `else` statement, and I think it can be done.

Algorithm is like this -

> If `user_ptr` exists, then `lock attrmap`, find `user_ptr`. And if it
>   is a `batch`, then don't ping. And else if `user_ptr` doesn't exists
>   and if it is not a `batch`, then do other stuff.  But if it is a
>   `batch` and `user_ptr` doesn't exists, then don't do anything.

With the above algorithm, this is what I've came up with, but I'm not sure whether it can be simplified or not.

```
if (user_ptr) {

    if(batchOrTimestamp != "batch") {
        user_ptr->ping(); // dont ping it if its a batch update
    }

    // lock attribute map from outside access and modification
    AttributeMap::GuardSPtr guard = user_ptr->m_attrMap.get_guard();
    user_ptr->m_attrMap.find(column_key.c_str(), actual_binary_value, attributeLength, schemaId, lastModifiedDate);
} else if(!user_ptr && batchOrTimestamp != "batch") {
    user_ptr = User::MakeUser(user_id);
    user_ptr->m_attrMap.find(column_key.c_str(), actual_binary_value, attributeLength, schemaId, lastModifiedDate);
    User::Find(user_ptr);
}
```

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: You *could* technically simplify it by expressing results in values and run the values through a 'switch' block.

Comment: *else if(!user_ptr* <-- the !user_ptr check is redundant in this case. That branch won't be reached if user_ptr is not 0 anyway.

Comment: @AlexM. so in that case, this is sufficient - `else if(batchOrTimestamp != "batch") {` right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have is essentially:

```
if (a) {
   if (b) c();
   d();
}
else if (b) e();
```

Where:

```
a = user_ptr
b = batchOrTimestamp != "batch"
c = user_ptr->ping();
d = 2 lines, starting with `AttributeMap::GuardSPtr guard = user_ptr->m_attrMap.get_guard();`
e = 3 lines, starting with `user_ptr = User::MakeUser(user_id);`
```

One way to rewrite this is:

```
if (a && b) c();
if (a) d();
else if (b) e();
```

And another way is:

```
if (b) {
   if (a) c();
   else e();
}
if (a) d();
```

Which of these ways you prefer is up to you. The problem is that you have a total of three branches. One for `a`, one for `b && !a` and one for `a && b`.

I don't believe it's possible to **simplify** this in a better way (I would gladly be proven wrong).

Comment: Thanks Simon a lot. And apart from this, whatever I have in my updated code in my question is also right? Correct? And we can rewrite this in two ways as well as you have suggested?